# Optimize 2D array multiplication numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do a quite memory intensive multiplication and it seems that I am always filling up my RAM. The idea is that I have a 2D gaussian centered in (0,0) and then I have another 2D gaussian that changes its distance with respect to the (0,0) point in time. For each time I need to compute the product of the two gaussian on a specific grid and sum all over the indices. Basically I should end up at each timestep I should have *SUM{g1<sub>ij</sub> g2<sub>ij</sub>} and end up with a 1D array of the same length of time

The code here is just a pseudo-code. The problem is the creation of a 1001x1001x25000 array here `xx[:,:,np.newaxis]` which gives a huge array

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

def gaussian2d(x,y,x0,y0,x_std,y_std):
   return np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/x_std**2-(y-y0)**2/y_std**2)

x = np.linspace(-5,5,1001)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,1001)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

g1 = gaussian2d(xx, yy, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25)

x0 = np.random.rand(25000)
y0 = np.random.rand(25000)

X = np.subtract(xx[:,:,np.newaxis], x0)
Y = np.subtract(yy[:,:,np.newaxis], y0)

X_std = 0.75
Y_std = 0.75

temp = ne.evaluate('exp(-(X)**2/(2*X_std**2)-(Y)**2/(2*Y_std**2))')

final = np.sum(np.multiply(temp.T, g1), axis=(1,2))
```

A very slow alternative would be to just loop along the x0 length, but in future x0 may be as long as 100000 points. The other solution would be to reduce the grid. But in that case I would lose resolution and if the fixed function is not a gaussian but something different may affect calulations.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you looking to do a 2D convolution?

Comment: Also, did you mean `gaussian2d` in g1 = `gauss2d(xx, yy, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25)`?

Comment: Did you compute the amount of RAM needed? 2 * 1001 * 1001 * 25000 * 8 = 373 GB (of float64) to store *X,Y*.

Comment: @MadPhysicist basically yes I need to do a 2D convolution, the problem is computing the second array which is a gaussian varying with time. And yes I meant ```gaussian2d```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I don't need to store those data. I just need the ```final``` array. The problem is to compute it I need that amount of RAM

Comment: *final* can be computed with *temp* computed in chunks of the time axis. An implementation depends on the actual *x0, y0* (I suppose some kind of orbit or trajectory, where *t(+1) = t(0) * something*). With random values it is just an additional for loop.

Comment: @MadPhysicist just to specifiy that the problem here is related to generate that NxNxT matrix that I need to convolve with ```g1``` (which is NxN). So I need to convolve NxN arrays for T times.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I am trying to avoid the for loop. I tried it and it takes way too long 25000 values. The x0 and y0 in my application are not random, but the evolve in a non linear way

Comment: Chunks (e.g. 250 chunks of 100 time steps) are a compromise between a full for loop and computing everything in an array (which seems not possible).

Comment: I will try that way, I don't see any other options at the moment.

Comment: The two dependences can be factorised, so maybe you come along without having the full x, y mesh, and do the convolution with oen variable at a time?

Comment: Did you benchmark a for loop?  I benchmarked a (100,100,200) one-array against a full for loop: **6.31ms vs 4.78ms (one-array is ~1.3x faster)**. With chunks 1.02x faster. Did you use `np.append` to collect *final* inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes I use append

Comment: @GiovanniTardini I haven't come up with a good way yet

Comment: Does this help? [Python: Speeding up a slow for-loop calculation (np.append)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295576/14277722)

Comment: As mentionend below, I solved the memory issue using `np.einsum`. I am now trying to understand if I can write things differently to speedup a bit

Comment: You can speed up the computation of the exponential (in fact, Numba is 4 times faster for that without using an efficient exponential implementation internally), but you cannot write a faster code than einsum does in this case (assuming the BLAS implementation is efficient and correctly configured). The einsum call take about 60-70% of the time on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for all such HUGE arrays. `xx` and `yy` as well as `X` and `Y` contains 1001 times the same repeated line/columns which is a **huge waste of memory**! The RAM is a very scarce resource (both throughput and space) so you should avoid operating on very large array (so to use the CPU cache which are far much faster or even CPU registers). You can rewrite the code using loops and use a JIT compiler like **Numba** (or a static compiler like Cython) so to run this efficiently by removing all the big arrays. In fact, thinking about loops can help to optimize the operation further even in pure Numpy (see later). So Numba/Cython is not even needed. Here is a naive implementation:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(f8[:], f8[:], i8, i8, f8[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(x0, y0, N, T, g1):
    X_std = 0.75
    Y_std = 0.75

    final = np.empty(T)
    for i in nb.prange(T):
        s = 0.0
        for k in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                X = x[k] - x0[i]
                Y = y[j] - y0[i]
                temp = np.exp(-(X)**2/(2*X_std**2)-(Y)**2/(2*Y_std**2))
                s += g1[k, j] * temp
        final[i] = s
    return final

N = 1001
T = 25000
# [...] (same code as in the question without the big temporary arrays)
final = compute_clever(x0, y0, N, T, g1)
```

This code is **much faster** and use only a **tiny amount of RAM** compared to the initial code that could not even run on a regular PC. The same strategy can be used to compute `g1` so not to create `xx` and `yy`.

Actually, the above code is not even optimized. On can **split the exponential expression in two parts** so to pre-compute partial results using only basic math. The computation can then be factorized to reduce the number of mathematical operations even more. Here is a better implementation:

```py
@nb.njit('(f8[:], f8[:], i8, i8, f8[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute_clever(x0, y0, N, T, g1):
    X_std = 0.75
    Y_std = 0.75

    final = np.empty(T)
    exp1 = np.empty((T, N))
    exp2 = np.empty((T, N))
    for i in nb.prange(T):
        for k in range(N):
            X = x[k] - x0[i]
            exp1[i, k] = np.exp(-(X)**2/(2*X_std**2))
    for i in nb.prange(T):
        for j in range(N):
            Y = y[j] - y0[i]
            exp2[i, j] = np.exp(-(Y)**2/(2*Y_std**2))
    for i in nb.prange(T):
        s = 0.0
        for k in range(N):
            s2 = 0.0
            for j in range(N):
                s2 += g1[k, j] * exp2[i, j]
            s += s2 * exp1[i, k]
        final[i] = s
    return final
```

Here are results with N=1001 and T=250 on my 6-core machine:

```
Naive Numpy:      2380  ms    (use about 4 GiB of RAM)
compute:           374  ms    (use few MiB of RAM)
compute_clever:     55  ms    (use few MiB of RAM)
```

Note that the code can be further optimized using **register blocking** though it will make the code more complex. Also note that the last kernel can certainly be computed efficiently using **`np.einsum`**. `exp1` and `exp2` can also be computed using basic Numpy operation (though it will be a bit less efficient). Thus, you could even solve this using a pure Numpy code.

Comment: The problem is that for my specific case I cannot use numba or cython. I’m writing a series of functions for a specific package and this already uses mpi4py (the pseudo-code here is in a for loop parallelized with mpi, so I can’t add other parallel code ). My bad that I have not specified it

Comment: So this actually means that the code you provided is not representative of the actual code? This is critical since the solution can drastically change regarding such "details" and without them the question can hardly be answered. Anyway, AFAIK Numba can be used with mpi4py and you can just remove the `parallel=True` and `nb.prange` so to make it sequential. Even if Numba is a still problem, the end of the question point out an einsum-based solution that can be quite written from the last function. By the way, AFAIK NumExpr also run codes in parallel so the problem was already present...

Comment: The use of *numexpr* is due to the fact that is significantly faster than `np.exp` and it seems that is not affecting mpi4py. Following your suggestion, I wrote the code in this way: 
`def method2(g1, x, y, x0, y0):
    v = np.exp(-(x[:,np.newaxis]-x0)**2)
    n = np.exp(-(y[:,np.newaxis]-y0)**2)
    
    return np.einsum('ij,kj,ki->k', g1, v.T, n.T, optimize='optimal')
`
This does not use a lot of RAM (I can run it on my laptop with N=1001 and T=25000) and it takes around 30s

Comment: This is a relatively good implementation. By the way note that `einsum` with an `optimal` schedule also use multiple cores exactly like the Numba code does (AFAIK it uses a BLAS implementation internally like OpenBLAS or the MKL which uses multiple threads. You need to configures the threading layer of BLAS implementation to avoid an inefficient over-subscription.

Comment: I think I will remove the `optimal` flag. It also does not change the path with respect to the `greedy` when looking at `np.einsum_path`